# Topic Words Selection in Topic Modeling

Tags: distributions, topic-models, generative-models

I understand how generative model of topic modeling works; for each topic there is a distribution of words, and for each document there is a distribution of topics.

Question is how words are determined for each individual topic ? Does this change algorithm to algorithm ?

**Edit:**

Such as:

Topic-1 : internet, web, search etc.

Topic-2 : literature, novel, etc

I wonder how "internet, web, search" are chosen for topic-1. Why "internet" and "web" take place in same topic instead of separate topics? Is it because they frequently coexist in different documents?

Comment: idk what this means *"how bag of words is determined for each individual topic"*. please clarify.

Comment: Are you basically asking how topic models work?

Comment: I think he is asking how to algorithmically pick the descriptive words inside a particular topic to summarize the topic.

Comment: In response to your flag, metdos, I would suggest to wait some days--at least the time of the bounty--before taking any action on your question (which you can do yourself by the way).

Answer (score 4):

In standard topic modeling, each topic is a discrete probability distribution over the entire vocabulary. However, after performing inference it is generally the case that only a few words have significant probability mass in each topic. For example:

```
Word        Probability
----------  -----------
internet    0.2
web         0.15
search      0.08
  .
  .
milkshake   0.000002
```

The above topic assigns very high probability to words related to the internet, but it also assigns some non-zero probability to *every other word* in the vocabulary (including, for example, milkshake).

Since most words in the vocabulary have very small probability under this topic, we can summarize the topic by only showing the highest-probability words. Such summaries might make it look like each topic is a distribution over a different subset of words, which I think is the source of your confusion.

Comment: But how algorithm decides to increase probability of "internet" and "web" for topic-x instead of topic-y ?

Comment: You can try to look for more explanation on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation

Comment: Ah, I see you are really just asking for an explanation of how topic modeling "works". There are many explanations with varying levels of detail already available online. I suggest you read one or two, and then come back here if you have *specific* questions that are hindering your understanding.

Comment: Drew, I up voted your answer.  I wonder, what is the best way of choosing a cut-off value? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199263/choosing-words-in-a-topic-which-cut-off-for-lda-topics

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is because they frequently co-occur across documents. LDA is a probabilistic model that describes a process for how documents are generated, namely by randomly choosing a set of topics and then randomly choosing words from those topics. The topics themselves are hidden variables which seek to account for why groups of words tend to co-occur together within documents. So, the goal of topic modeling is to use some inference method that seeks to **discover** the hidden topics that best explain the co-occurrence patterns of words across documents. It is closely related to [probabilistic latent semantic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis).